# how to use 'starts with' on all vowels in python?

Tags: python, string

I just stumbled upon how to check if a string starts with a vowel?

```
def f(s):
    s = s.split(' ')
    for word in s:
        if word.startswith(any('aeiou')):
            print('starts with a vowel')
    print(s)


r = 'd sljf l23j lekj 023 fls erj 50 isdl usdlw '

f(r)
```

But it gives error, what's wrong? any() is a bool function, it should print what word starts with a vowel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startswith` takes in string, you can try this.

```
r = 'd sljf l23j lekj 023 fls erj 50 isdl usdlw '

for x in r.split():
    if any(x.startswith(v) for v in 'aeiou'):
        print(f'{x} starts with a vowel')
```

---

```
erj starts with a vowel
isdl starts with a vowel
usdlw starts with a vowel
```